# SQL get distinct values but showing all rows with Symfony Doctrine

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine, distinct

I have a table like :

```
a.id; a.username; a.mail; a.optin
```

Considering theses values :

```
1; tobby; tobby@google.com; true
2; franck; tobby@google.com; true
3; john; john@google.com; true
```

I would like (in SQL, but also in Symfony with Doctrine) to get ALL values and ALL rows (id, username, mail, optin) BUT Distinct by email.

With SELECT DISTINCT mail, I only have mails....

Could you help me please ? Thanks !

Comment: If you only want distinct mails, then in your example for the row where mail = tobby@google.com, what do you want to return for username? Sounds like you are talking about aggregation possibly.

Comment: Is it possible to have something like :
[
1; tobby; tobby@google.com; true
2; franck; tobby@google.com; true
][3; john; john@google.com; true]
With an additional generated row "nb_itteration" containing the number of occurences (2) ?

Comment: Maybe rephrase and add more detail to your question, as it doesn't sound like you want DISTINCT. Sounds like you want something involving COUNT.

Comment: which RDBMS do u use?

Comment: $em->createQuery('SELECT DISTINCT ....)

Answer (score -1):

```
$qb = $em->getRepository('Your Entity here')->createQueryBuilder('a')->groupBy('a.mail');

$result = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Here's more explanation:
The first line builds your query with a select all columns of the entity you fill in and the groupBy will give you distinct rows by email.

In MySql the query generated from this is equivalent to:
SELECT * 
FROM 'Your Entity here'
GROUP BY mail

Comment: Please add more details to your answer.

Comment: flagged up in the lqp queue.  Please add an explanation of how this answers the OP's question.